# WP ALL Import Load Image filtering by xml node attribute

Tags: xml, wordpress, simplexml, wpallimport

I have this xml nodes

```
<file_allegati>
  <allegato id="0" planimetria="0" type="foto">
    <id>0</id>
    <file_path>https://##.jpg </file_path>
  </allegato>
  <allegato id="1" planimetria="1" type="planimetria">
    <id>1</id>
    <file_path>https://##.jpg </file_path>
  </allegato>
</file_allegati>
```

And i would like to split image with attribute "planimetria=1" and write the file_path into a custom field.

I can't use [FOREACH] method of wpallimportso I try to call function named set_planimetrie(file_allegati[1])

And the I wrote this php function but it doesn't work.

```
function set_planimetrie( $allegati ) {
    $result="";
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($allegati); 

    foreach($xml->children() as $allegato)
    { 
        if($allegato['type']=='planimetria' && $allegato['planimetria']==1){
            if( $result != ''){$result .=',';}
            $result.= $allegato->file_path;    
        }
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about "doesn't work" - does it give the wrong output, or an error message, or cause smoke to pour out of your computer...?

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the first value of the `foreach` because you use the `return` statement inside the foreach.

The return type of `$allegato['type']` is [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). You could get the string using [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) or use `(string)`.

If you put the return statement outside of the foreach, and use the `(string)` to get your value your code would look like:

```
function set_planimetrie($allegati)
{
    $result = '';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($allegati);

    foreach ($xml->children() as $allegato) {
        if ((string)$allegato['type'] === 'planimetria' && (string)$allegato['planimetria'] === "1") {
            if ($result !== '') {
                $result .= ',';
            }
            $result .= $allegato->file_path;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Output php example](https://3v4l.org/v9d7U)